# im new to learning Javascript. wondering why the condition worked when it wasnt linked to the field in the constructor

Tags: javascript, class, conditional-statements

Was going over tutorials and came across this. when the Class was created. "minutesWatched" wasnt linked( ie by "this.minutesWatched = minutes.watched") so how it was still able to work using the condition given. when passed through console.log it worked  and gave a response like as usual. did i miss something?

```
class Episode {
  constructor(title, duration, minutesWatched) {
    this.title = title;
    this.duration = duration;


    if (duration == minutesWatched) {
      console.log(true);
    } else {
      console.log(false);
    }
  }
};



let firstEpisode = new Episode('Dark Beginnings', 45, 45);
let secondEpisode = new Episode('The Mystery Continues', 45, 10);
let thirdEpisode = new Episode('An Unexpected Climax', 60, 0);
```

an Example to further clarify what i mean.

```
  class Episode {
  constructor(title, duration, minutesWatched) {
  this.title = title;
  this.duration = duration;


   }
  }

   let firstEpisode = new Episode('Dark Beginnings', 45, 45);

   console.log(firstEpisode);
```

return

```
      [object Object] {
      duration: 45,
      title: "Dark Beginnings"
      }
```

see theres no `minutesWatched` key/value as it was not linked in the constructor?

thats why i dont quite understand how the condition in my first code worked well without `minutesWatched` being linked (i.e by `this.minutesWatched = minutesWatched` in the constructor. how? thats what i dont quite get.

hope my question is clear now.

Comment: `minutesWatched` is available throughout the constructor function because it is a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

Minutes watched is passed in as a "parameter" to the function. You can see that in the constructor method, there are 3 variables in the parenthesis. These variables can be used throughout that method (enclosed in the curley brackets).

For example (taken from [Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)):

```js
let Rectangle = class {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
};
```

You can see the "this" keyword sets the class variables to their respective values based on the parameters passed in through the constructor

You can learn more about parameters to functions here: [W3Schools JavaScript Function Parameters](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_parameters.asp)

In regards to your issue with the "linking" of the variables. It might be beneficial for you to rename the variables set with the "this" keyword, and see the result.

Set your class equal to this, and look at the result:

```js
class Episode {
  constructor(title, duration, minutesWatched) {
    this.episodeTitle = title;
    this.episodeDuration = duration;


    if (duration == minutesWatched) {
      console.log(true);
    } else {
      console.log(false);
    }
  }
};
```

You will notice that when you log the object, it now says

```
Object {
  episodeDuration: 45,
  episodeTitle: "Dark Beginnings"
}
```

This is because the `this` keyword creates a "property" related to the instance of your current class.

When you're logging the class, you're not actually seeing the `duration` variable that you passed, you're seeing the `this.duration` property that you created at the beginning of your constructor.

The `minutesWatched` parameter can be called within the constructor, meaning that you can use that variable within that method, however it will not be logged until you say `this.minutesWatched = minutesWatched` because when you log the class, you're logging the properties of that class (the properties are defined using `this.<property_name>`)

Hopefully this makes sense, leave a comment and I'll add more clarification here

Comment: Terrible example! The *direct* scope of `class <name> { ... }` allowes no statemens, only methods (property functions) of the class!

Comment: @NiklasE. Apologies, this was my first ever stackoverflow answer, and I typed it in a hurry.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, much better now. I hope I didn't demotivate you... continue your help on SO.

Comment: still unclear to me. if theClass (Episode) was passed without the condition. the objects would not include the "minutesWatched" value when logged. since the variable "minutesWatched" was not set. its why im confused about my question. better clarification?

Comment: @tonybaidoo But you are passing "minutesWatched". That's the third parameter in your episode instances.

`let firstEpisode = new Episode('Dark Beginnings', 45, 45);`
They are passed in the order you give them. Dark beginnings becomes "title", 45 is "duration", and the second 45 is "minutesWatched"

Comment: @tonybaidoo I understand your issue now, and I have updated by answer accordingly.

Comment: im trying to show an example. but cant quite quite out how to type the code properly in the comments

Comment: @JohnnyLeek kindly recheck my question

Comment: @tonybaidoo I added a little more to the end of my answer, but I feel like im going over the same point over and over again. I can't really add more explanation to what I have already provided. The second example I gave should be a good visualization of your problem.

Comment: @tonybaidoo To put it simply, the reason that if statement works is because it is within the constructor body. If it wasn't located where it was, the code would not run.

Comment: @JohnnyLeek much clearer now. thanks alot. been of great healp.